# Is there a PIE feminising noun suffix?

Tags: etymology, historical-linguistics, proto-indo-european

I was wondering whether anyone knows the Proto-Indo-European equivalent of the Greek suffixes -ina (-ίνα) or -issa (-ισσα), or whether PIE has any different feminising suffixes that work similarly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main PIE feminine derivational suffix was *-ih2*: compare *deiu-o- 'god' with *deiu-ih2 'goddess' (Skt. *devī*).

Incidentally, this suffix is actually the indirect source of the Greek suffix *-ssa*: when added to a stem ending in -t or -k, you get e.g. *melit - *melit-ih2, which becomes in Greek *melitya and then *melissa* (Attic *melitta*). From cases like these the suffix was reinterpreted as being *-ssa* and extended to other types of stems (e.g. *basilissa* 'queen').

Answer (score 0):

The feminine suffix in PIE is believed to be -i̯ea̯, though the ablaut grade in nominative is not certain. Traditionally reconstructed as -i̯ea̯ (because of long vowels in Latin), but Beekes hypothesizes that the Nominative form was -ia̯, while in other cases it could become -i̯ea̯. A form -a̯/-ea̯ also can be seen in some words.

The suffix is believed to originate from the suffix -ia̯ for collective number.

Some reconstructed PIE words with the suffix include

***a̯oldhia̯*** a dugout boat

***a̯eua̯ia̯*** grandmother

***bhrea̯tria̯*** brotherhood

***colia̯*** hiding place, dug-out

***e̯rudhia̯*** rust

***deiu̯ia̯*** goddess

***e̯sntia̯*** being

***ma̯eghu̯ia̯*** young woman

***neptia̯*** nephew (fem)

***pie̯u̯eria̯*** fat woman

***preu̯ia̯*** lady, mistress

***potnia̯*** lady

***u̯eĝhia̯*** track, road

- Most animals had feminine form

***a̯ena̯tia̯*** duck

***e̯ele̯nia̯*** female elk

***cu̯nmusia̯*** dog-fly

***melitia̯*** honey-bee

***plusia̯*** flea

***u̯lq̆ia̯*** she-wolf

The suffix could be combined with other suffixes as well, to form constructs like -ikea̯/-ika̯/-ikia̯, -tria̯/-tra̯/-teria̯, -nia̯, -u̯ia̯ etc.

Comment: Zero grade is the nominative seems pretty clear, given Greek -ia and Skt. -i:.

Comment: (In case it isn't clear to the OP, this is the same suffix I mentioned in my answer -- just a different transcription.)

Comment: @Anixx: I've seen your PIE reconstructions in a bunch of threads and I'm always puzzled by what your notation represents. What are the 'inverted under-breves' meant to be? Semivowels? Do you not reconstruct laryngeals?

Comment: @TKR actually tha ablaut grade could be different per word, like the ablaut case in -os/-s, don't you think so?

Comment: Also, at of general curiosity, do you use a single source for your PIE facts or do they stem from multiple sources?

Comment: @Olivier there are multiple sources always. What exactly facts do you mean?

Comment: Your first sentence, to start with. Then all the rest.

Comment: @Olivier multiple sources, Beekes, Fortson and a lot of others. Is there something that looks doubtful for you so that you ask for supporting sources? Also see the second comment by TKR.

Comment: No, no, nothing looks doubtful to me (in fact, I'm completely ignorant of this topic), I was just hoping to learn reliable sources for these questions and since you obviously know a lot about it, I wondered where you had acquired your knowledge (that said, supporting sources are always good, but in that case, it was just sheer curiosity on my part).

Comment: *actually tha ablaut grade could be different per word, like the ablaut case in -os/-s, don't you think so?* -- I'm not sure; which -os/-s do you mean? In any case, what's the evidence for an e-grade in the nominative here? All the words you list show zero grade.

Comment: @TKR I mean there are thematic and athematic nouns, some having ending -os, others having ending -s in nominative. The same could be with the feminizing suffix.

Comment: But that's not ablaut, that's a lexical difference in stem type. The nominative ending is the same -s in both types.

Comment: @TKR hmm I saw this theory in some sources, but most sources count the thematic vowel a part of the ending. The ablaut in the ending, similar to the ablaut in suffixes and the root.

Comment: I don't think I've ever encountered that view of the thematic/athematic difference. Since the thematic vowel occurs in all the cases, I don't see how it can be part of the nominative ending.

Comment: This answer confuses two suffixes: PIE *ih2/yeh2 and PIE *iH (commonly denoted as *ih2, although I don't know what the basis would be for saying it's *h2). A word like *deyw-ih2-/-yeh2- "goddess" is formed with the former suffix, and a word like *wlkw-iH- "she-wolf" is formed with the latter suffix. The difference between these two suffixes is seen in their inflection, cf. e.g. the nom.sg. fomrs *deywih2 vs. *wlkwiHs.

Comment: @Sverre source for the form "wlkwiHs"?

Comment: @Anixx If it's allowed, I can refer to my own [thesis](http://folk.uio.no/sverrej/publication_files/2005/dissertation/johnsen_mphil.dissertation.2005.pdf) on this suffix.

Comment: @Sverre feel free to make your own answer. I do not know about your theory.

Comment: @Anixx I agree with TKR's answer, actually. Also, what I write about these two suffixes in PIE in my thesis is not idiosyncratic. Anyone claiming that the nom.sg. forms were not *deywih2 vs. *wlkwiHs would be idiosyncratic. And the field of PIE research is filled with idiosyncratic opinions, unfortunately ...

Comment: @Sverre TKR does not mention two suffixes, he mentions only one. You are free to add an answer that would mention the second one.